# prove: if B $\subset A$, then Probability(B) $\le$ Probability(A)

Tags: probability

B $\subset A$, then P(B) then P(B) $\le$ P(A)

I've seen a video to this answer and some yahoo answers to this question but it's still not clear to me how you derive the answer.

Comment: Given a set $A$, how do you define $P(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is a probability measure, then it satisfies countable additivity and nonnegativity. So consider $X_1=B$, $X_2=A\backslash B$, and $X_n=\emptyset$ for all $n\geq 3$. Because $B\subset A$, $\{X_n\}$ constitutes a countable collection of disjoint set. So countable additivity implies
$$
P(A)=P(\cup_nX_n)=\sum_n P(X_n)=P(B)+P(A\backslash B)+P(\emptyset)+P(\emptyset)+\cdots=P(B)+P(A\backslash B).
$$
Now use nonnegativity $P(A\backslash B)\geq 0$.